# Build a nonprincipal ultrafilter such that containing a infinite subset

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, filters

I'm try generate a nonprincipal ultrafilter such that containing a infinite subset. I know that this ultrafilter is generate via the ultrafilter lemma, I should build a filter that contains the infinite set with infinite complement and then extend it using the ultrafilter lemma, but I'm not sure how to build such a filter, here I have an idea, I don't know if be correct.

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that $A$ and $\mathbb{N} \setminus A$ are inifite.

$\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{F}_r \cup \mathcal{F}_A \cup \{   
X \cap Y \mid X \in F_{r} \text{ and } Y \in F_{A}  \}$

where $\mathcal{F}_r$ is the Fréchet filter and $\mathcal{F}_A$ is a filter generate by $A$.

I'm not sure that $\mathcal{F}$ is a filter, if $\mathcal{F}$ is a filter then the problem is solved

Comment: What do you mean, "build?" There is no constructively defined non- principal ultrafilters.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews you are right, what I really want is to generate an ultrafilter with said property, just to know that it exists

Comment: "Generate" is still a problematic word. All you can do is show one exists.

Comment: $F=\{X\subseteq\mathbb N:A\setminus X\text{ is finite}\}$ is a filter.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It is true, but I want to know if the filter that I built is actually a filter, because if it is so, then by the ultrafilter lemma my problem would be solved

Comment: @bof yes bof, that is Fréchet filter

Comment: I'm interesting in know that this $F=Fr∪FA∪ \{X∩Y∣X∈Fr and Y∈FA\}$ is a filter. I think so, but I'm not sure

Comment: @bof Sorry, I saw wrong, that's a good solution, thanks.
One last question, mine $\mathcal{F}$ is wrong?

Comment: @JamesR. It's not "wrong", it's just a more complicated definition of the same set.

Comment: @JamesR. Note that $\mathcal F_F\cup\mathcal F_A\subseteq\{X\cap Y:X\in\mathcal F_F\text{ and }Y\in\mathcal F_A\}$.